# tinymce for drupal: bad text formatting

Tags: drupal, tinymce

**I install the Wysiwyg TinyMCE for drupal 7.23, and when i apply some formating for my text i get as output in my website HTML's tags, like what illustrate this picture :**

[image]

**but when i write the text by the Wysiwyg  it looks correct :**

[image]

so please how can i fixe this issue ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `BBCode` is activated in your TinyMCE configuration. Disable it so that the editor generates classic HTML.

To disable, you need to go to Configuration > Content > Wysiwyg profiles > Edit (on all your used formats `Filtered HTML`, `Full HTML`, ...) > Buttons and plugins > Uncheck `BBCode` checkbox > Save

Comment: Yeah thank you that really help me. please i don't get colors in my text just black and the size is not changing. ? :)

Comment: TinyMCE generates inline styling to define the font color, sizing which is filtered by Drupal when rendering the page. Do you use the `Filtered HTML` format? Try using the `Full HTML` format which normally doesn't filter HTML attributes.